# Sub menu wont show when menu item hovered over (css html)

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover

I have a simple navigation with a sub-menu on one of my main navigation items. When the user hovers over this i would like the sub-menu item to show and when you go onto the sub-menu li items the main menu link to still have the background colour 'hovered' state still active. Thing is i cant even get the sub-menu item to show!

I have tried the usual `display:none` and when `:hovered { display:block};` but it's ignoring it.

What am u missing? Must be something so simple but cannot see in the css styling.

Here is a link to an example of how it is setup: http://jsfiddle.net/ULSsa/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the [demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/ULSsa/6/) http://jsfiddle.net/ULSsa/6/ with corrected css

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    }
body {
    font:normal 12px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#000;
    padding:20px;
    background-color:#F2F2F2;
    }
ul, li, ol {
    list-style-type:none;
    }


ul#nav-1 {
    width:60%;
    height:46px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
ul#nav-1 li {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    *float:left;
    margin-top:16px;
    margin-left:-4px;
}
ul#nav-1 li a {
    padding:22px 13px;
    font-size:14px;
}
ul#nav-1 li:hover a,
ul#nav-1 li a:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:#000;
}
ul#nav-1 li ul#sub-menu {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    list-style:none;
    left:0;
    top:19px;
}
ul#nav-1 li:hover ul#sub-menu {
    display:block !important;
}
ul#nav-1 ul#sub-menu li {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
}
ul#nav-1 ul#sub-menu li a {
    border-bottom:1px solid #dbddd4;
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
    width:200px;
    text-align:left;
    display: block;
    padding:0;
    padding-left:18px;
    padding-top:13px;
    padding-bottom:13px;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
}
ul#nav-1 ul#sub-menu li:hover a {
    background-color:#3a3a3a;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

Comment: Just what i was after. Thanks for the update of the css too, tidy and everyones answers answered my question!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy. The submenu `ul#sub-menu` is not a child of the anchor element, but of the list element. You must either put the submenu inside the anchor element or check for the hover on the list element as following:

`ul#nav-1 li:hover > ul#sub-menu {` instead of `ul#nav-1 li a:hover > ul#sub-menu {`

http://jsfiddle.net/ULSsa/2/

Answer (score 1):

Just change your `ul#nav-1 li a:hover > ul#sub-menu` to `ul#nav-1 li:hover > ul#sub-menu` because the submenu it is a child of `li` and not of an anchor (`a`).

[See the example by clicking here](http://jsfiddle.net/ULSsa/1/).

If you do not know, the CSS `>` selector means the specifically child of the element.

### Updated

To maintain the link state, just do this:

```
ul#nav-1 li:hover a {
    background-color: black;
}
```

[See the example by clicking here](http://jsfiddle.net/ULSsa/7/).

Comment: These answers are great(cant accept any answers for 5 more mins) but the active background on the main nav item doesn't keep it's state when the drop down is displayed. Is this something i will have to do via jQuery or simply css?

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong selector here, it should be

```
ul#nav-1 li a:hover + ul#sub-menu { /* Note the + sign instead of > */
    display:block !important;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ULSsa/3/)

Explanation: You are using `>` which will select direct child elements of `a` which in your case are none, so you need to use `+` adjacent selector to trigger the adjacent element

Comment: Just curious... how well is this supported on somewhat older browsers?

Comment: @Chris It's well supported :) http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector